# Equivalent of `within` for Angular Spectator Testing

Tags: angular, angular-spectator

When using react-testing-library, the `within` method allows me to use the matchers to find elements within parts of the HTML.

I can see that I can pass a *string* selector in the properties of a DOMSelector: `byText('Name', {selector: '.name'})` but this means I can't use the nice `byText`, `byTitle` etc to build up more complex selectors, I would have to implement them myself as plain query selectors, something like:

```js
byText('Name', {selector: '[text="Name parent label"].parentElement'})
```

Whereas I would like to use the power of the `by*` DOMSelectors to write:

```js
byText('Name', {within: byText('Name parent label').closest('div')})
```

Am I missing something, or is this a feature that Spectator currently doesn't have?

Comment: if you are already familiar with `react-testing-library` why are you not using `angular-testing-library`

Comment: @RachidO Good question. I did use that! On my last project! It wasn't a great experience because it is a port of a library focussed on React testing, Spectator is designed for use with Angular. Other devs were begging to not use angular-testing-library.